# Temporal complexity of primary instructions in C

Tags: c, time-complexity

I have a question about algorithmic complexity.

Do the basic instructions in C have an equivalent complexity, if not, in what order are they:
if, write/read a single cell of a matrix, a+b, a*b, a = b ...

Thanks

Comment: You might be looking for something like this from a theoretical perspective? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations

Comment: its the cpu architecture that defines the cycle count or throughput of the instructions.

Comment: The basic instructions that you've listed have the same complexity O(1), but that doesn't mean they take the same amount of time. Complexity is an academic concept that's used to compare the theoretical performance of algorithms (especially when run on large data sets). If you're trying to make an engineering decision between two algorithms, you need to implement both, and then benchmark them with typical use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The basic instructions in C cannot be ordered by any kind of wall-time or theoretic complexity. This is not specified and probably cannot be specified by the Standard; rather, these properties arise from the interaction of the code, the OS, and the underlying architecture.

I think you're looking for information on [cycles per instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycles_per_instruction).

However, even this is not the whole story. Modern CPUs have hierarchical caches. If your algorithm operates on data which is primarily in a fast cache, then it will run *much* faster than a program which operates on data that must be repeatedly accessed from RAM, the hard drive, or over a network. The amount of calculation done per load is an application's *arithmetic intensity*. [Roofline models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roofline_model) provide a tool for thinking about this. You can achieve better cache utilization via [blocking and other techniques](https://github.com/r-barnes/how-to-optimize-gemm), though the subfield of [communication avoiding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication-avoiding_algorithms) explores this in-depth.

Ultimately, the C language is a high-level abstraction of what a processor actually does. In standard cost models we think of all instructions as taking the same amount of time. In more accurate, but potentially more difficult to use, cache-aware cost models, data movement is treated as being more expensive.

Comment: I'm working on a big project that needs to be as fast as possible, so I have to choose between algorithms. So, I can assume that the execution of a'condition' is as fast as a matrix writing. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are saying.

Comment: @ElexXVII: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. If you're deciding between algorithms then the the relative speed of `if` and `a+b` is unimportant. What matters is the complexity of the algorithm and its communication/cache patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Complexity is **not** about the time it takes to execute "basic" code lines like addition, multiplication, division and so on.

Even if these expressions have different execution time they all have complexity O(1).

Complexity is about what happens when some variable figure changes. That variable figure can be many different things. Some examples could be "the number of element in an array", "the number of elements in a linked list", "the size of a file", "the size of a matrix".

For instance - if you write code that has to find the largest value in an array of integers, the execution time depends on the number of elements in the array. The code will have to visit every array element to check if it's larger than the previous elements. Consequently, the complexity is O(N), where N is the number of elements. From that we can't say how much time it will take to find the largest element but we can say that it will take 10 times longer to execute on a 1000 element array than on a 100 element array.

Now if you did the same with a linked list (i.e. find largest element) the complexity would again be O(N). However, this does **not** say that a linked list perform just the same as an array. It only says that it scales in the same way as an array.

A simplified way to say it - if there is no loops involved the complexity is always
 O(1).